# Работа с видео в С#-приложении

Tags: c#, видео, youtube

Решил написать программу, с помощью которой, допустим, можно смотреть видео с YouTube.

Есть ли какой-то общий алгоритм работы с видео в С#? Какие библиотеки использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если делаете в приложении WinForms, то проще всего использовать компонент WebBrowser и в нём вопроизводить ссылки на видео. Причём, ссылки должны быть, как во встраиваемом видео. (код для вставки на веб страницу). Других способов не вижу.

Comment: Вообще, почему я такое спросил, о WebBrowser это да, но, допустим, я даже не знаю, возможно ли так, есть сайт, на котором транслируется телеканал, можно ли это видео загружать оттуда в Windows Media Player в WinForms и показывать, то есть сделать такую себе прогу для просмотра теле-радио. Возможно, вы посоветуете какую-нибудь книгу по работе с аудио и видео в шарпе, потому что я пока ничего стоящего не нашел. (

Comment: Можно использовать компонент [WindowsMediaPlayer][1]. 
Нашёл для Вас [интересное видео][2]. Думаю, поможет. 


[1]: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/programminglanguageru/thread/b633cc15-43a8-4eff-8a8b-a2fbdc57068e/
[2]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kg-z8JfOIKw

Comment: благодарю)

Comment: отличное видео,помогло)) еще раз удивляюсь как в шарпе достаточно все удобно и просто)

Comment: Тут больше не заслуга сишарпа, а платформы .NET, которая при создании была призвана упростить создание пользовательских приложений под Windows. Однако, эта простота создаёт большую конкуренцию между .NET программистами. Ведь писать такие приложения - легко. Поэтому каждый должен уметь делать нечто большее, чем перетаскивать компоненты на формочку и писать пару строк кода:)
з.ы. ответ засчитан?:)

Comment: да я об этом всегда думаю поэтому и пока думаю куда дальше двигаться в сторону шарпа,Java или податься в плюсы,с другой стороны всегда хороших спецов мало в любой области

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу, если вы используете c# web browser, вы полностью зависите от версии Internet Explorer установленной на компьютере. Например для просмотра html5 видео вам потребуется ie9+. Соответственно нужно при старте приложения установить режим совместимости с более высокой версией ie.